# How PDFBox detect columns?

Tags: java, pdfbox, multiple-columns, text-extraction, identity-column

I'm trying to extract text from pdf documents. I've tested several tools like `PDFBox`, `TET`, `PDFTextStream` and so on, but none of them is good for extracting the text of Persian multi-columns pdf documents.

Currently I'm trying to combine good features of this tools and using some tricks on them. Now I want to know that how I can detect number of columns of a page and how to split the texts of these columns.

Specially I want to know which class of `PDFBox` or `PDFTextStream` is responsible for column detection and how it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speak for `PDFTextStream`, but in order to understand how it works, you want to understand, roughly, how `PDFTextStream` looks at a PDF document.

Each document is made up of `Pages`, which are made up of `Blocks` (of which there can be many and nested). `Blocks` will ultimately contain `Lines`, which will contain `TextUnits`.

Each of these units have an `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` property. All a PDF is are these basic units laid out based on their coordinates. When you ask `PDFTextStream` to "read" a page, or a region, it looks at the objects and how they are laid out on the X, Y plain and use an approximation of how that would translate to text. This is why you get errors, because there's no 100% foolproof way to turn this structure into machine-readable, structured data.

In `PDFTextStream`, you should look at the `getRegionText` [function and example](http://downloads.snowtide.com/javadoc/PDFTextStream/2.6.0/com/snowtide/pdf/RegionOutputTarget.html). PDFTextStream is proprietary (the reason why I'm moving to PDFBox), so I can't give you details about the algorithms used to fetch the text, but they're based on the above oversimplification.

Good luck.

Comment: `PDFTextStream` is as just as you described. I have deeply traced its main objects and the [interfaces](http://downloads.snowtide.com/javadoc/PDFTextStream/2.3.2/com/snowtide/pdf/PDFTextStream.html) of these objects. I think its `API` is really straightforward. But the main flaw of `PDFTextStream` is that it not support `Right-to-Left` scripts (like Persian, Arabic and Hebrew). So I have moved to `PDFBox` too! But `PDFBox` has bug in text extraction of `RTL` pdf documents, however it support them. I think it has `Work-Flow` architecture and so it is very hard to debug. thank you anyway.